# SIPP testing calling to asterisk

Tags: asterisk, sipp

I have finished SIPP configuration, and I want to test my asterisk server, is there any way on SIPP only call 10 times then stop automatically? what the command? I only know this command "**./sipp -sn uac -d 10000 -s 1001  -l 10**", but this ink can not stop automatically

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.td-er.nl/index.php?title=SIPp_command_line_parameters

```
  -m               : Stop the test and exit when 'calls' calls are processed
```

Answer (score 0):

Add -m to command line.

```
./sipp -sn uac -d 10000 -s 1001 -m 10
```